# Dependencia dos serviços

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, services

Tenho um serviço que fecha uma entrada no estoque. Como todo processo de entrada ao cadastrar a nota tenho o cadastro manual de cada item da nota e ao fechar a nota preciso atualizar o estoque de cada item desta nota.

Fiz o seguinte método no meu serviço:

```
public class EstoqueEntradaService : BaseService<SAR_ENTRADA> 
{
    public void FecharEntrada(SAR_ENTRADA model)
    {
        model.Status = 'F';

        foreach (var item in model.Entradas)
        {
            var estoque = item.Material.Estoque.Where(m => m.Almoxarifado == item.Almoxarifado).SingleOrDefault();

            if (estoque != null)
            {
                estoque.Quantidade += item.Quantidade;
            }
            else
            {
                item.Material.Estoque.Add(new Estoque()
                {
                    Almoxarifado = item.Almoxarifado,
                    Material = item.Material,
                    Quantidade = item.Quantidade
                });
            }

            item.Material.CustoMedio = (item.Material.CustoMedio + item.ValorUnitario) / 2;
            item.Material.UltimoValorCompra = item.ValorUnitario;
            item.Material.UltimaDataCompra = DateTime.Now;
            item.Material.Fornecedor = model.Credor;
        }

        this.Edit(model);
    }
}
```

No processo de fechamento da entrada eu altero o status para fechada e faço uma listagens de cada item desta entrada atualizando o estoque, se existir ou inserindo um novo registro no meu estoque para aquele produto, por almoxarifado.

**Minha dúvida é:** Devo manter essa parte de atualização do estoque dentro de um serviço que se refere a entrada e não os items do estoque ou devo nesse serviço de entrada chamar o serviço de estoque em um método por exemplo: AtualizaEstoque, que recebe a ID do almoxarifado e do material e ai sim atualizar o estoque por lá?

Vlw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Penso que a ideia de fazer outro serviço atualizar o estoque pode complicar desnecessariamente a solução, a não ser que o novo método `AtualizaEstoque` seja utilizado por outras partes do seu código, aí sim sendo pertinente a separação.